# Minecraft Player Heads show Steve when worn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I want a player head, and in this example we'll use Notch.

```
/give Jigsaw79 minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:Notch}
```

So it gives me a head. When I place down the head it shows Notch's skin, but when I put it on, it's just a Steve head. How do I fix it so it looks like a player when worn?

Comment: You should try quotation marks around the player name. `/give Jigsaw79 397 1 3 {SkullOwner:"Notch"}`

Comment: No, it doesn't show when I put it on my head. But as I said above in my edit, it shows when I place it down.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the new player identifier. A player used to be uniquely identified by his Name, which is why renaming your character was just impossible, since the game would register a new player instead.

Starting from Version 1.7.6, specifically [Snapshot 14w10b](https://mojang.com/2014/03/minecraft-snapshot-14w10a/),

> [...] All server files that are intended to refer to players will be automatically **changed to go by UUIDs** (=Universally Unique Identifiers), and you do not need to do anything. [...]

emphasis and parenthesized part mine. This means, that the correct command to spawn Notch's head is no longer:

```
give @p skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:Notch}
```

but, according to the description of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6zd3xGIa1Q):

```
give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:{Name:"Notch",Id:&­quot;069a79f4-44e9-4726-a5be-fca90e38aaf­5",Properties:{textures:[0:{Value:&­quot;eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjEzOTczMDc4NzUyNjM­sInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6IjA2OWE3OWY0NDRlOTQ3MjZ­hNWJlZmNhOTBlMzhhYWY1IiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWU­iOiJOb3RjaCIsImlzUHVibGljIjp0cnVlLCJ0ZXh­0dXJlcyI6eyJDQVBFIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9­0ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmU­vM2Y2ODhlMGU2OTliM2Q5ZmU0NDhiNWJiNTBhM2E­yODhmOWM1ODk3NjJiM2RhZTgzMDg4NDIxMjJkY2I­4MSJ9LCJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh­0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvYTE­xNmU2OWE4NDVlMjI3ZjdjYTFmZGRlOGMzNTdjOGM­4MjFlYmQ0YmE2MTkzODJlYTRhMWY4N2Q0YWU5NCJ­9fX0=",Signature:"aT80QC+msQMa­ew55CcyxRF8VpCsuHLJvEQNbsdQTSi4v2VACgGXE­kLZkmMIWwOdUgeT+juEbzNCNPf3knDn56W4HKqS/­f0ppMUHoWPXl4/XWHsfxG7iSwq6MkBF90GwqGEjC­BuDG4ZQnHpEOBQXxa8bmrhZoXJjMBXhO3EAiB37H­b7V+C1xX9H5p+JkzXao1Ca3WEYimC+2QQa3gGoPI­rHR/4c47EbZj7cuGarQzTdCyZEYd3adFF67oFOhg­miYYHIabT2d5Ejh5PTwJHIjKGw1Uo+qjrEeBWKTF­HZ86t5eSa8pZGkmjxFxn2oaKUz8PsopW5b5DlS3C­iZo3IQE0oa8Fisncoab1pIsj0P80rrugTBRCg/pb­EJls7dUpJs5l3xJ7XFujYT8a7O0bjksX87z9KJHO­fsN5LjFoQS6oA5qDXu2Fy6loYZy5h2XnjcWQzWHZ­WwaxgJPKYIS8zjx63ussFy3JhaCNp5BVqQKRbB6w­zGt2nXScBKhPUf76eJViIpBVfZ1ZerYCMyj0GKdh­u3DnLMrK1qbi05IzKGNzGoDZfTxh6wZtXJFMTXk1­EO/sAAiMgN3OpFn3IV8YA36rDkindA4LZI327dQV­mvV9Rt3/U8J7n4bNLJRRfgXsZbg+Yn7yF20+Z3Qk­fm80kTiu2hci1Dl2A7dscahBjD08JLE="}]­}}}"﻿
```

When you place the head down, it will be automatically converted into the new format, but not when you wear it. [It's a known bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-51003), that is fixed in upcoming versions, probably 1.8 release or a newer snapshot.

For now, try placing the head, break it, pick it up and then wear it.